# Bootbox Confirm Does Not Submit Form in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bootbox

Im trying to use BootBox Confirm in ASP.NET MVC 5.

I have this JavaScript code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#close", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to close this Service Request? This operation cannot be reversed.", function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        $this.submit();
                    } else {
                        console.log("user declined");
                    }
});
```

With this button: `<td><a href="@Url.Action("CloseLog", "Log", new {id = item.LogID})"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" id="close"></span></a>`

However, the form does not submit when I press the ok button on Bootbox. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In that scope, `$this` is the *button*, not the form. You can't submit a button. You could do:

```
$this.closest('form').submit();
```

Comment: Is 'form' suppose to be the name of my form? I'm not sure how to find the form name

Comment: Ok I've named my form to 'frm' and changed the code but still not working

Comment: any help from anyone??

Comment: No, jQuery uses CSS-style selectors. That's saying get the closest form element parent to this element.

Comment: Any suggestions as to whats needed to submit the form?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean what code is needed to submit the form when I press the ok button on Bootbox dialog?

Comment: The code I gave you in my answer. As long as you're dealing with an actual form element in your jQuery, you just call `submit()` on it.